# Python check that key is defined in dictionary

Tags: python, hash, dictionary

How to check that the key is defined in dictionary in python?

```
a={}
...
if 'a contains key b':
  a[b] = a[b]+1
else
  a[b]=1
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use the `in` operator:

```
if b in a:
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
>>> 'foo' in a
True
>>> 'spam' in a
False
```

You really want to start reading the Python tutorial, the [section on dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) covers this very subject.

Answer (score 8):

Its syntax is `if key in dict:` :

```
if "b" in a:
    a["b"] += 1
else:
    a["b"] = 1
```

Now you may want to look at `collections.defaultdict` and (for the above case) `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
if a.has_key('foo'):
    a['foo']+=1
else:
    a['foo']=1
```

Comment: This can't be used in Python 3, better to use `in`

Answer (score 1):

```
if b in a:
     a[b]+=1
else:
    a[b]=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parsedData=[]
dataRow={}
if not any(d['url'] == dataRow['url'] for d in self.parsedData):
       self.parsedData.append(dataRow)
```